# Passing HTML through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

### The goal

Pass to the DOM strings with HTML and render it.

### The scenario

I'm extending properties of an observable (with KnockoutJS) using the follow syntax:

```
self.showDetails.subscribe(function (context) {
    var details = this.showDetails();
    details.nameWithCnpj = context.name() + " <small>" + context.cnpj() + "</small>";
}, this);
```

If you pay attention on the following line, you can see the HTML on it:

```
details.nameWithCnpj = context.name() + " <small>" + context.cnpj() + "</small>";
```

When the `<small></small>` tag arrives on the HTML, it is rendered as string instead of vanilla HTML.

The container that houses the `nameWithCnpj` (using KnockoutJS) is the following:

```
<h2 class="bold float-left" data-bind="text: nameWithCnpj"></h2>
```

So I ask: **How can I teach to JavaScript (or HTML) that the `nameWithCnpj` variable should be a DOM element instead of a simple string?**

Comment: It depends on how do you display the `nameWithCnpj`, please post the code where you display the content of `nameWithCnpj `!

Comment: Sorry, @nemesv. Take a look on the main post now — I updated it.

Comment: Don't you think a binding would be more appropriate? You're taking a mvvm and closely coupling UI logic in the model.

Comment: @BradChristie Are you saying to me for use `html` binding instead of `text`? (Just for curiosity)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: I'm saying with a MVVM the minute you're placing html in the _model_ you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @BradChristie Then, how can I perform the following syntax with KnockoutJS + MVVM correctly?: `<h2>Something Here <small>Here too!</small></h2>`.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge in my opion the absolute correct way is to create a template for your `details` object and use the `template` binding in your view. But if you are going to use this `<h2>Something Here <small>Here too!</small></h2>` only in one place in your app then the `html` binding and formatting in your view model is perfectly fine. There is no such thing as MVVM police :)

Comment: @nemesv I'm using the `template` binding in my view, but I don't know how to render `<small>` within `<h2>` tag.

Comment: In general, i agree this isn't "harmful", but I assimilate mixing views and models as drug fixes; At first you start small with those "exceptions"/"I'm just going to get it working" types, but eventually you're hooked and it becomes a maint. nightmare. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie I agree with you — and this is the first time that I do something like this with KO —, but I know not better ways. Can you show me something better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) instead of `text`:

> The html binding causes the associated DOM element to display the HTML
>   specified by your parameter.
>
> Typically this is useful when values in your view model are actually
>   strings of HTML markup that you want to render.

So change your view to:

```
<h2 class="bold float-left" data-bind="html: nameWithCnpj"></h2>
```

If you want to be more MVVM you can create a template which encapsulates your formatting logic and use the  `template` binding:

```
<h2 class="bold float-left" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'nameWithCnpj', data: showDetails}"></h2>

<script id="nameWithCnpj" type="text/html">
   <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
   <small data-bind="text: cpnj"></small>
</script>
```

Comment: yes! that's why there are models & views. though I'd take it a step farther and get `<small>` the heck out of that property then create a `nameWithCnpj` binding all on its own.

Comment: @BradChristie yeah in general I agree, but the `html` binding exists for a good reason, sometimes you have some generated 3th party html what you need to display (like in CMS apps) so it is not bad to use but. In this concrete case if this is the only usage of this HTML fragment creating a one time only custom binding seems overkill for me...

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge I've extended my answer with a sample template usage.

Comment: nemesv AMAZING TEMPLATE USAGE! I believe it was my lack of creativity, haha. By the way, thank you so much for your and @BradChristie attention. Thank you, thank you & thank you guys!

Comment: Aw, no virtual elements? ;p gj nemesv